# Does it make sense to have a PHP class just for cleaning/escaping user input?

Tags: php

My application persists a large amount of data into a MySql database, and I'm wondering if I should handle the cleaning/escaping with a separate class, or if this is overkill? Also, I'm using prepared statements with PDO, so I'm not exactly sure how much cleaning or escaping data I should be doing in combination with binding parameters.

I'm aware of the old Perl adage, "There's more than one way to do it," so I'm not asking for an actual solution. I'm just trying to weigh the benefits of calling in another class to handle the escaping, or if the simplicity of this process would better be handled locally.

Comment: If you already use PDO and bind parameters, I wonder a bit about which kind of "cleaning" or "escaping" you ask here. One thing you could check for example is, if the charset used in the input is correct. So maybe you can elaborate a bit what this is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to do so, then why not? There's no overkill when putting stuff in a class and then requiring it. It will also allow you to test your code.
I don't see another way to do that anyway, except using bare PHP functions.

By the way, PDO does escaping. You class would only handle *cleaning*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there is a *right* answer to this or not, but we do actually use a class for just the reasons that you're talking about.  It gives us a standard place to do the standard scrubbing, but in our case, it also allows us to apply our business rules to data before it lands in the database.  In fairness, we pass more than just the data itself to do that, but it's a nice central way for us to have some control over general input from our users.

Comment: We have various configurations in the use of this class.  A simple example is handling "bad" words.  Sometimes we want the string replaced with asterisks, other clients want the data flagged, etc.  Again - all centralized for easy management.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that depends on how it is structured your application, I usually have an Util class with methods for this kind of stuff, but if you have some (or lot) methods for cleaning input data you can create a subclass for it.

Like *Grep P* said, the're not right or wrong answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add additional code there will be *someone* who claims that it runs `X.XX` micro-nano-junior-seconds slower.  Weighing the benefits could only be subjective so I think that you'd need to make a decision for yourself.

Escape the data with a class or with some global function collection in a utility file; The only really important thing is that the code you use is easily understandable and that the next developer who looks at it will not have to tear his hair out [wondering what on earth you were thinking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfAk7.png)